# Image Plots components

Tags: plot, ilnumerics

At page 136 of the user manual of ILNumerics CTP (RCh), there is a mention to an Image Plot, in the "future section".

Is this the name of a new coming component similar two the TwoDMode of a 3D surface in a PlotCube, but optimized for 2D rendering or so? Could you describe its use case/functionalities?

(I would appreciate to have the possibility to quickly draw image plots (like Matlab imagesc) even with GDI backend. Currently GDI is to slow to render 700x700 ILSurface objects in a PlotCube with TwoDMode=true.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagesc - as you noticed - can be realized by a common surface plot in 2D mode. A 'real' imagesc plot would hardly do anything else. If the GDI renderer is too slow on your hardware, I'd suggest to

- switch to an OpenGL driver, or
- decrease the size of the rendering output, or
- prevent from transparent colors (Wireframe or Fill), or
- decrease the number of grid columns / rows in the surface

Note, the GDI renderer is mostly provided as fallback for OpenGL and for offscreen rendering. It utilizes decent scanline / z-buffer rendering. But naturally, it is not able to deliver the same speed as hardware accelerated OpenGL driver. However, 700x700 output should work even with GDI - on recent hardware (at least a couple of frames per second, I would guess).

Comment: I will stick to surface plot in 2D mode and OpenGL rendering for the moment. On my machine, GDI needs a few seconds to render a 500x700 surface in 2D mode with wireframe and transparency disabled. Using a recent machine with Intel Core i7-3630QM @2.40GHz.

Comment: this sounds strange. Are you using a Release build? Not in debug mode (Ctrl+F5 in VS)? Just curious - using OpenGL is always recommended of course.

Comment: The delay in updating a surface in a plotcube is further discussed there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742746/how-to-efficiently-plot-a-large-surface-e-g-1000x1000-in-ilnumerics